# For loop index undefined in IE9 for initial pass

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

On this page: http://koncordia.marketingassociates.com/19892arc/

I have a slideshow that I created custom prev/next links for. Each selection you make on the page advances it one slide forward. The progress bar at the top allows you to click a previous slide, and jump more than one back if you want (you can go from step 4 or step 1 for example).

This multi-step jump works fine in all the current major browsers, but the client uses IE9, and this is where I do not understand the source of the issue.

The following are the relevant methods in this issue. To mimic a user jumping back one or more slides I have a `for loop` iterate over *simulatePrevClick()* as many times as necessary; it's not sexy but it works.

The issue arises on the initial pass in IE9. The console spits out "undefined" for the first pass, but it says 0 for all other browsers (including IE 10 and 11) which is correct. If I remove the method call within the loop the iteration works perfectly, so it has something to do with the .click() event or way the method is called, but I don't know what.

No matter what, IE9 will show the immediate previous slide no matter how many they click back; the progress bar be out of sync if they click back more than one in this instance. The undefined result is not showing as an error, either.

```
    //Highlight the right number of progress buttons
    highlightProgressBar: function( slideNumber ) {
        $(".btn-progress").attr('disabled', 'disabled').removeClass('active'); //Disabled all
        $("#progress-wrapper a:lt(" + slideNumber + ")").removeAttr('disabled'); //Disable select number
        $("#progress-wrapper a:eq(" + (slideNumber - 1) + ")").addClass('active'); //Add active to the specified button clicked
    },

    simulateNextClick: function () {
        //The value of this must match what the responsiveslides function creates for the prev/next buttons (seen when you inspect element)
        $(".transparent-btns_nav.transparent-btns1_nav.next").click();  
    },

    simulatePrevClick: function () {
        //The value of this must match what the responsiveslides function creates for the prev/next buttons (seen when you inspect element)
        $(".transparent-btns_nav.transparent-btns1_nav.prev").click();
    },

    toggleProgressBar: function( clickedSlideNumber, activeSlideNumber ) {
        var numSlides = activeSlideNumber - clickedSlideNumber;
        for (var i=0; i < numSlides; i++) { //Anticipate user may click more than one step back
            this.simulatePrevClick();
            console.log(i); // **shows "undefined" on first pass in IE9 only**
        }

        this.highlightProgressBar(clickedSlideNumber);
    }
```

Comment: `i` as undefined? what is the value of `numSlides`?

Comment: `numSlides` has a legitimate integer value, otherwise it would fail in all other browser as well

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the `var i = 0` declaration out of the loop.

```
var i = 0;
for (; i < numSlides; i++) {}
```

It's really strange that that should happen.

Comment: Nice idea, but still get 'undefined'.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but I looked through the rest of your source code, and its possible that the root of your problem could be due to whenever you actually implement your `toggleProgressBar` function, in this area:

```
$(".btn-progress").click(function() {
    var currentSlideID = $("#progress-wrapper").find('a.active').attr('id').split("-");
    var clickedSlideID = $(this).attr('id').split("-");
    slideFn.toggleProgressBar( clickedSlideID[1], currentSlideID[1] );
});
```

If I see right, your `toggleProgressBar` wants to accepts two numbers.  However, what you're passing in are string literals:

```
slideFn.toggleProgressBar( "2", "1" );
```

ID attributes are output as strings, *not* numbers.  I just tested the following in Chrome, and it worked:

```
"2" - "1" === 1 //true
```

This is because I guess V8 (Chrome's JS engine) coerces the two string literals into numbers.  However, (while I have not tested it), this tells me that it's possible that IE might not be coercing the two strings into numbers (like I said, I don't know this for a fact, but this is something you might try debugging).  Try this and see if it has any effect:

```
//first option

slideFn.toggleProgressBar( +clickedSlideID[1], +currentSlideID[1] );
//the + sign will typecast your strings into numbers


//second option

slideFn.toggleProgressBar( parseInt(clickedSlideID[1]), parseInt(currentSlideID[1]) );
```

However, in my experience, `parseInt` runs a little bit slower than using `+` to typecast the strings into numbers.

IE uses the Chakra JS engine, which I believe follows the standards of ECMAScript 3, which is from 1999.  I haven't read through the standard, but it's worth considering the possibility that it has something to do with the issue.

## Edit

Here's your problem:

```
$("#progress-wrapper").find('a.active') ==> []
```

The first time, there are no `a.active` elements.  Thus, whenever you try to call `split` on an empty array, it throws a `TypeError`.

You need to give your first `.btn-progress` the class `active`, because the first time around, your first `.btn-progress` looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript://" class="btn btn-progress btn-progress-one btn-xs" id="step-1" role="button">1</a>
```

There's no `active` class.  Only subsequent `.btn-progress` elements receive the class `active` whenever you click the `.btn-continue`.  Your first one never does.  Therefore, `clickedSlideID[1]` and `currentSlideID[1]` are undefined the first go around.  It probably breaks in IE9 because IE9 doesn't understand `i < undefined`, but it's possible that other more modern browsers go ahead and execute anyway.

Somewhere in the beginning of your code, then, you need to do something like this:

```
$('.btn-progress').eq(0).addClass('active');
```

I just tried this in the console on your page, and it worked just fine.  After I added the class `active` to the fist `.btn-progress`, `currentSlideID[1]` was now `1`, and not `undefined`.

Comment: I'm not seeing this work for me, but I never heard of the plus sign being used to cast in JS so at least I learned something new. I'm using IE11's developer tools to emulate so I am not sure if that has any effect on this.

Comment: FYI, I don't have access to the above address so I'm testing all changes on a local instance.

Comment: Okay. Something else potentially too is that your subtracted values are resulting in "0", "", NaN, or undefined, all of which can be coerced to the undefined type.  Something I might suggest is using the console to see the value of clikedSlideID[1] and currentSlideID[1] before they're passed into your function (i.e. are they string literals?  Are they numbers?  What is the result of the subtraction?)

Comment: Also try logging your array.  Is there any value currently occupying the 1st index when you pass those values into your function?

Comment: @AngrySpartan, see my edited answer.  I've found your problem.

Comment: Just to point this out since there was doubt, `"2" - "1"` should work as expected in any browser as per ECMAScript spec. Even `"2" + "1"` works consistently across all browsers (just *not* the way you'd typically expect).

Comment: Is the viewable slide accurate to the progress button that's highlighted for you? I'm still seeing the slide only go back one no matter how many steps back you click the progress link.